# Rewrite URL - dynamic url stripping

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite an url like this: http://www.piata-bio.ro/presa-bio.php?var1=http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNHmU7U7bXtlH9Lo8dXfBs64PqxgbA&url=http://www.eva.ro/divertisment/stiri/un-nou-concept-de-magazin-articol-35491.html

to something like this : http://www.piata-bio.ro/presa-bio.php?var1=www.eva.ro/divertisment/stiri/un-nou-concept-de-magazin-articol-35491.html

Basically I want to strip to google news part and only remain with the final url (without the "http://").

I've been trying all sorts of solutions but nothing worked so far.
FYI - I use wordpress

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(?:http://)?(.*)
RewriteRule presa-bio.php presa-bio.php?var1=%1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by matching the query string in a rewriteCond :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(?:http://)?(.*)
RewriteRule presa-bio.php presa-bio.php?var1=%1 [L]
```

(If the ?: does not work with rewriteCond, loose it and use %2 instead of %1 in the next rule).

Comment: Thanks for you replay. Unfortunately it did't work. There was no change in the urls.

Comment: @Mike Johnson: please post you .htaccess as an edit (with code formatting) will be much more clear! (And can help other to try formulated answsers)

Comment: If this does not work, can you add change to [L,R] to see in the browser where does the redirect takes you?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what change you're referring to. `I modified RewriteRule presa-bio.php presa-bio.php?var1=%1 [L]` to `RewriteRule presa-bio.php presa-bio.php?var1=%1 [L,R]` and there was no change.

Comment: I mean, [R] flags make redirection, so you are redireted to a new page and the changes are reflected in the browser address bar. So you can tell how the address has been rewritten. What does your browser displays? 404? another page?

Comment: I've tested it on my config. Without the rewritebase it seems to be working. maybe try : `RewriteRule presa-bio.php /presa-bio.php?var1=%1 [L]`. You can also try to activate mod_rewrite logs. (`RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"  RewriteLogLevel 4`)

Comment: I've removed rewritebase and also tried the new line, but still.. no change. I've tried to activate rewritelog but everytime it made the server return a 500 Internal server error

Comment: Any clue in the error.log? (the two rewrite directives are separated by a carriage return, I've not precised it.)

Comment: Whenever I add the 2 lines of code (the two rewrite directives) my server returns 500, but it also creates the error_log. In this log I can see this `XML_ERR_NAME_REQUIRED at line 39, column 29`.  A quick-search revealedthat " only happen when there is a '&' character in my XML file"

Comment: I've solved the issue a different way, (just parsing the url= value). Thanks for all your help.